# How to pass data from express-validation middleware to next function?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-validator

I have an express app that looks like this.

```
const app = require('express')();

// Task model
const Task = require('./models/Task');
const { param, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const getTaskValidations = [
  param('id')
    .custom(async (id, { req }) => {
      try {
        const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: id, user: req.user.id });
        if (!task) Promise.reject('Task not found');
      } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
      }
    })
]

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: errors.array()[0].msg });
  }
  next();
}

// Get Task by id
app.get('/tasks/:id', getTaskValidations, validate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = await Task.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(task)
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle err
  }
})
```

I want to get the task by id. In `GET tasks/:id` the req.params.id will contain the id of the task.
The Task Model looks like this

```
{
  id: 
  task: 
  user:
}
```

By looking at the endpoint it is clear that I'm passing two middlewares.
The first middleware `getTaskValidations` will check if the task will given id and req.user exists.
The second middleware `validate` will check for errors.
And then again will query database for task and send data to the client causing 2 database queries.
How can I reuse the same `task` obtained in the `getTaskValidations` middleware.

Comment: The title of question could be wrong. But I have explained everything in the post.

Comment: Hi Pranjal, the explanation looks OK, but I think if you ask a question, it might help for this entry to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

you can add result of query add to the req.body.task like this

```
const getTaskValidations = [
  param('id')
    .custom(async (id, { req }) => {
      try {
        const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: id, user: req.user.id });
        req.body.task = task
        if (!task) Promise.reject('Task not found');
      } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
      }
    })
]
```

in controller

```
app.get('/tasks/:id', getTaskValidations, validate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let {task} = req.body
    res.json(task)
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle err
  }
})
```

Comment: I wonder if it would cause any performance issues

Comment: it's better use `findById` instead of `findOne` and use select some filed that you need them

Comment: usually using a token with `jwt` module, not this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can store the response you get from the query in the request(`req`).

```
const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: id, user: req.user.id });
if (task) 
     req.task = task;
else 
     Promise.reject('Task not found');
```

Later on, in the API endpoint, you can simply use

```
app.get('/tasks/:id', getTaskValidations, validate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = req.task;
    res.json(task)
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle err
  }
});
```

to get the `task` obtained in the `getTaskValidations` middleware.